# How to get consistent ethernet device numbering on a Raspberry pi?

Tags: systemd, ethernet

I have a Raspberry pi 3B+ with a custom Yocto Linux image.
I want the onboard Ethernet to be eth0 and a USB Ethernet dongle to be eth1 or something else such as usb_eth0.
One pi consistently numbered the onboard Ethernet as eth0, but on a second device the USB dongle is always initialized as eth0 and the onboard one as eth1. I want to use eth0 for ssh and eth1 to have a different ip address and connect to a different network. But my configuration in /etc/network/interfaces and my application both use hardcoded names.
I tried to change this behavior in several different places. Such as in systemd/network.

/etc/systemd/network/10-eth1.link:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=00:14:5c:9c:67:3b

[Link]
Description="White USB ethernet dongle"
NamePolicy=
Name=eth_usb
```

journalctl -b:

```
kernel: usb 1-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
kernel[275]: [  609.282053] usb 1-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
kernel: usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-1.1.2: Product: AX88179
kernel: usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
kernel: usb 1-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 00000000000:;3
kernel[275]: [  609.418133] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel[275]: [  609.418148] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel[275]: [  609.418157] usb 1-1.1.2: Product: AX88179
kernel[275]: [  609.418166] usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
kernel[275]: [  609.418175] usb 1-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 00000000000:;3
kernel: ax88179_178a 1-1.1.2:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:14:5c:9c:67:3b
kernel[275]: [  609.780308] ax88179_178a 1-1.1.2:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.2, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:14:5c:9c:67:3b
systemd-udevd[563]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v243'.
systemd-udevd[563]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
systemd-udevd[563]: [[0;1;31m[[0;1;39m[[0;1;31meth0: Failed to rename network interface 5 from 'eth0' to 'eth_usb': Device or resource busy[[0m
kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
kernel[275]: [  610.139890] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
systemd-udevd[563]: [[0;1;38;5;185m[[0;1;39m[[0;1;38;5;185meth0: Failed to process device, ignoring: Device or resource busy[[0m
systemd-networkd[288]: eth0: IPv6 successfully enabled
```

As you can see it fails to rename.

I also tried to change /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:14:5c:9c:67:3b", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="neweth0"
```

But this too failed.

I also tried to add /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link. But it seems like this file is completely ignored.

I tried several tutorials, but none of them seem to work on my device.
I would like any USB Ethernet dongle to have the same name (I connect max 1 dongle, so no chance of collision) that's different from the onboard Ethernet. I prefer not to use MAC addresses in configuration files since those differ between boards and dongles.